# date-fns: set time format for chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, date-fns

I'm starting to use `date-fns` and I want to choose a language to correctly format X axis at `chart.js`, but I couldn't understand how to achieve this.

From this (https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns#configuration) I see what lines I must add, but I don't know what to do with the `import` line. If I write it into JS file I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

At console I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at` regarding the code below from `index.js`.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { //error points here
  value: true
});
```

As I understood, *somewhere else* should set this language and then export it to my JS code, therefore making it light since it only has what I explicitly requested. While `moment.js` had everything bundled, it was easy to apply but slow on daily usage.

I've found many references to this but not yet explaining where/how/when to use this.

Can someone explain or maybe inform where can I learn this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using chartjs-adapter-luxon

example:

```
adapters: 
       {
        date: {
                  zone: 'UTC+6',
                  locale: 'de-DE'
              }
        }
```